# find files in linux with some exceptions

Tags: find

I am trying to make a command which will find all the files modified in past 24 hours and which are PHP only with a loop to look into each public_html directories  and save the output into a HTML file so i can view daily.

```
 for i in `ls /var/cpanel/users`; 
 do find /home/$i/public_html -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \; > 
 /home/demo4/public_html/output.html;
 done;
```

But it is not working properly and giving output not correct..
here is the output which is only for 1 account, it should be for all accounts

```
0 -r-xr-xr-x 1 ziaengg ziaengg 0 Jan 12 15:16 /home/ziaengg/public_html/modules/mod_rsflashmatic/xml/rsflashmatic_93.xml 23320 -rw-r--r-- 1 ziaengg ziaengg 23851008 Jan 12 15:25 /home/ziaengg/public_html/error_log
```

Also i would like to learn how can i email the result to any specific id..

And what parameter should i add if i want to exclude any file containing the keyword `cache`.
I am really new to this.

Comment: For mailing, try the `mailx` command: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html#30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
cd /var/cpanel/users &&
for i in *
do
    find "/home/$i/public_html" -type f ! -iname '*cache*' -ctime -1 -ls 
done > /home/demo4/public_html/output.html
```

Notes:

- Use `>>` instead of `>`, otherwise each iteration overwrites the output of the last. Or redirect the output of the whole loop, in which case you can use `>`.
- some `find` implementations have a `-ls` option which is quite like `-exec ls -ld {} \;`, so use it instead where available.
- Use the `!` operator to negate searches: `! -iname '*cache*'`
- if your `find` doesn't support the non-standard `-iname` predicate, use `-name '*[cC][aA][cC][hH][eE]*'` instead.
- Since these are usernames, you could use `for i in $(ls ..)`, but [it is safer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) to use `for i in *`.

Comment: you are awesome is there any way it put <br/> or breakline ?

Comment: @user38002 add a `-printf '<br />\n'` at the end of the `find` command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, yes. Dunno how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` on a GNU system with `uconv` and `recode`:

```
{ echo '<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"</head><body><pre>'
  users=(/var/cpanel/users/*(:t)) &&
    find /home/$^users/public_html -type f -ctime -1 ! -iname '*cache*' -ls |
    uconv --from-callback escape-c -f utf8 -t utf8 |
    recode u8..html
  echo "</pre></body></html>"
} > /home/demo4/public_html/output.html
```

(note however that `recode` doesn't support characters above U+FFFF)

You need those additional uconv/recode steps to avoid problems with filenames with `<` or `&` characters in their name or 8 bit byte values (here we assume file names are UTF-8 encoded (and for invalid characters, we display their byte values as `\xAB`)

Comment: this is something looks like pizza, i am learning how to make an egg right now :)

Comment: @user38002, then why make a html file and not a txt file? Making proper txt is easier than making proper html. And if you don't do it properly, then you introduce vulnerabilities (like some form of XSS with filenames like `<script>...`).

Comment: Since i am Web Developer i love HTML files and this is what i made http://demo4.inheritedarts.com/emailstats/ ... is this really vulnerable ? i will make txt file insted then and fetch it from php after it